# Force impact when lifting objects traveling at a relative velocity of 0

Tags: velocity, relative-motion, thought-experiment

During a break my colleagues and I came up with the following Gedankenexperiment I would appreciate if you guys helped us find the solution for:

- Truck (weight 5t) traveling at 80 kph with a tow-truck (weight 5t) on its loading surface
- Vehicle (weight 1t) traveling behind the tow-truck-truck at 80 kph
- While driving, the tow-truck lifts the vehicle driving behind the tow-truck-truck

What would happen? General consensus so far is that because the relative velocity is zero, the described procedure would be equivalent to a stationary tow-truck-truck's tow-truck lifting the vehicle (i.e. nothing would happen).

Is this correct? I am thinking that because of the tow-truck gaining mass as soon as it lifts the car, the tow-truck-truck is slowed down and the car would probably knock the tow-truck off the tow-truck-truck?

Comment: What makes you doubt of its correctness? The tow truck is not simply gaining mass, this is the case from the point of view of the moving truck, but from an observer in the highway the system also is unchanged, just connected but total velocities and momenta invariable.

Comment: Well, the tow-truck previously was not in any way attached to the vehicle that it lifts. When it does so, doesn't it become heavier (at least from the tow-truck-truck's point of view?)

Comment: Of you mean that note it's engine will have to exert more effort in keeping the speed, yes. But that is on conditions where you are considering friction, and one engine has to counter there effect where before there were two of them. But in space, with no , this would not be the case.